# Snowflake - constructing object from csv that contains a json column

Tags: json, csv, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, transform

I have an issue where I am trying to bring in data from a csv file that has mixed data. 9 columns are normal columns, where the last column has json.

I had to take out private data, this is how it is approximately. Ultimately the goal is to turn all of it into an object and insert it into a variant column of a table (the whole csv row converted to full json row).

My `import` table sample data in the csv/excel file:

```
| eID |   timestamp  |     event  | json data |
| --- | ------------ |    ------  | ---------
|  1a2e  | 04:24:10 AM |  login   | {"data": false, "id": 12, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"}
|  fe2a  | 06:00:00 AM | update   | {"data": false, "id": 13, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"} |
|  c4dd  | 09:12:02 AM |  profile | {"data": false, "id": 14, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"} |
|  e7a0  | 11:24:05 AM |  access  | {"data": false, "id": 12, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"} |
```

The end result should look like this in a snowflake raw json tables:

```
|    V (variant) |
| ------------ | 
| {"eID": "1a2e", "timestamp": "04:24:10 AM", "event": "login", "json data": {"data": false, "id": 12, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"}} |  
| {"eID": "fe2a", "timestamp": "06:00:00 AM", "event": "update", "json data": {"data": false, "id": 13, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"}}   |  
| {"eID": "c4dd", "timestamp": "09:12:02 AM", "event": "profile", "json data": {"data": false, "id": 14, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"}}    |
| {"eID": "e7a0", "timestamp": "11:24:05 AM", "event": "access", "json data": {"data": false, "id": 12, "email": "email@email", "identity": { "masked" : "uniqueidentifier-a2eee3"}, "logindate" : "2023-03-24TimestampNumbers"}}  |
```

It doesn't necessarily have an issue bringing into a table, it does that fine, but it is not formatted correctly in order to match a production table and brings in characters I don't want like backslashes \ and "

The table itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE DB.SCHEMA.TABLENAME
    (V VARIANT NOT NULL);
```

The insert code:

```
COPY INTO DB.SCHEMA.TABLENAME
    FROM (SELECT object_construct('eID', $1, 'timestamp', $2, 'event', $3, 'json data', $4) as obj
         FROM @internalstage)
         FILEFORMAT = (FORMAT_NAME = fileformat)
         FILES = ('csvfilename');
```

file format code (might need to change this?):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE fileformat
    type = csv
    field_delimiter = ','
    skip_header = 1
    null_if = {'NULL', 'null')
    empty_field_as_null = TRUE;
```

selected table makes data look like this (example 1 row):

```
|    V (variant) |
| ------------ | 
|{ "json data": "\" {\"\"data\"\": false", "eID": "1a2e", "timestamp": "04:24:10 AM", "event": "login" }|
```

It adds unnecessary characters, double quotes, and removes the closing } for jsondata nested and does not bring in all of what is in it. If anyone has come across a similar task as this, help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of defining the column as a `variant` in the table you are copying into, define it as a `string`.  Once the data is in Snowflake, you can transform the data using a `parse_json` function either on read or as a second hop of the data to your final target table.  This should work without any additional logic or removal of extra characters.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and comment in an answer once I've tested this.  To make sure I have this clear, I should simply bring the csv into a table normally, broken out into columns, and then copy that table into a variant table (parsing the rows into json)?

Comment: your json_data field would be a text field just like all the other columns in the csv file.  Then, the 2nd step would be to use `parse_json` on just that column on the way to another table that has that field defined as a `variant`